# Novel: Dystopian society with white monsters, military experiment, and an excursion party

Tags: story-identification

This was a novel by (probably) a popular author, but my memory is a bit faded on this one. Following is what I remember about the novel. I'll be very glad if anyone can help me identify the novel.

- Set in a dystopian society where the "normal human beings" are confined to forts and have to stand guard against creatures that run wild.
- It's dangerous to go outside the fort as the (probably) white monsters attack and kill humans with their claws. The monsters are likely white, soft, and furry with sharp claws.
- Something (water, electricity, etc.) inside the fort fails and a party has to be formed which takes an excursion to a (generator, water tank, etc.) station where they've to fix something. Many don't survive the expedition as they're attacked by the creatures.
- There was a small love story arc between one of the characters (who's also a part of the expedition) and one of the inhabitants of the fort.
- Likely turns out that the white monsters are a result of a (military) experiment gone wrong where erstwhile humans are changed into this white monsters. I vaguely remember a character (likely named B-o-b-c-o-c-k ) recollecting his past life when he was a human (and a few letters of his name).
- Likely one of the white monsters breaches the fort. But he was a friend/someone known so not much damage is done.

Not sure how the story ends. It's also a bit likely that I'm mixing up stories. It's a rather recent novel -- not too (> 20 years) old.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like [The Passage by Justin Cronin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Passage_(Cronin_novel)).

The monsters are vampires not white furry things, but otherwise everything fits. The vampires were created by a military experiment that went wrong, and Babcock was the first experimental subject and the process left Babcock with some vague memories of being human.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I'm currently reading The Passage by Justin Cronin and that's what set off the whole recollection of this old novel. Babcock is the name in The Passage which reminded me of the other novel with white furry things :( Sorry.

Comment: Dear @JohnRennie, let this comment be testament that a man can read a novel, completely forget reading it, its title, and author, and when re-reading, vaguely recollect the story itself and seek to find the book which he's vaguely reminded of. A bit of patience with the question would have gone a long way. I'll accept your (correct) answer to help others recollecting these events. Thanks!